# How can I detect visitor's country and redirect he/she to an specific website?

Tags: javascript

I have read several answers and I still don't know how to do it. I need to redirect my visitors  to an specific website depending on their country.I have some knowledge in html and basic javascript.

Could somebody paste the code they?

Comment: 1- It's annoying when sites do that. Do like amazon, offer the possibility with little icons to switch sites. Don't force people to switch. I hate when I get sent to a site in Russian/Chinese/Dutch/Swahili because I'm in Russia/China/Netherlands/Rwanda... 2- No, I can't paste my code because you can't use Google and StackOverflow.

Comment: @Kheldar -- you're kidding, right?  The OP is supposed to inconvenience entire countries because you can't be bothered to press the "English" button on the screen?  Ironically, you'll have to forgive any typos in this post because the computer here in Đà Nẵng wants to change (for example) "you" to `yêu`, `yểu`, or `yếu`.

Comment: @Malvolio : I think you are misreading me. What the OP is suggesting, done wrong, is an inconvenience to the Web at large. Done right, as in "as Amazon does it", it's OK. My point is precisely that I don't want to be pushed to another language because the server thinks it knows better than I, just as I don't want to be pushed to a mobile version of a site because I'm on mobile. I want choice, freedom. Not some jerk in Đà Nẵng or New York deciding what I will read in my place.  I hope you understand better my position, and be aware I don't press the English button, I'm not American :p

Comment: In other words: ideally, the website would suggest a customized version (localized, or mobile, etc), but never force it on me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i track the visitor's country and redirect them to appropriate sites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832380/how-do-i-track-the-visitors-country-and-redirect-them-to-appropriate-sites)

Comment: @Kheldar :  I think you are making a false distinction here.  The system (not necessarily the server, but something along the way) has to decide how to talk to you.  When you show up, it has to say "Hello" or "chào" or "bon jour" or *something*.  It isn't pushing you to *another* language, it's just pushing you to *some* language.  What else could it do?

Comment: "redirect" is the word used by the OP. Not "decide which language to show". As I understand it, it means user types zesite.com and then gets pushed to zesite.ru because he happens to be connected to a russian internet provider. That's bad.

Answer (score 5):

several ways to do this:

1. use GPS tag in HTML

   - requires permission from users - probably not widespread.
   - this is the most accurate
2. using IP address of the browser

   - most people use this and you get IP to Country mapping
   - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspxcode_net.aspx
   - not as accurate since browser can use proxy
3. using locale settings (eg. en-US, en-UK etc)

   - cheapest
   - not real location but 90% of users will set correctly.

Comment: I went with no.2 for the company website - only took an hour to implement.  The only problem is the IP databases get out of line quite quickly.  I noticed yesterday my 3G connection now shows me the German version of the website from England :)

Comment: @AmitBens **#3 is not very clever.** I'm from Australia and my site's analytics shows an overwhelming majority of users from Australia use en-US. When you go to install Firefox (and also Chrome, I believe), it suggests the locale which matches your operating system. Windows (before 8) is not available in en-AU, only en-US. Therefore, almost everyone in Australia has en-US by default, and very few people are motivated to change the default because we're all bilingual in en-AU and en-US.