# How to get user's country and forward to URL?

Tags: javascript, php, location, country

How can I get the user's country and forward them to a URL based on it?

I am looking specifically at Australia, New Zealand, USA, UK and Other.

Preferably with PHP, but can use Javascript if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you to get country then you can redirect accordingly.

```
<?PHP

  function visitor_country()
  {
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result  = "Unknown";
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
       $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
      $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
      $ip = $remote;
    }

    $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));

    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
    {
       $result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName;
    }

    return $result;
}

echo visitor_country(); // Output Coutry name [Ex: United States]

?>
```

OR in Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script language="Javascript"> 
document.write("Welcome to our visitors from "+geoplugin_city()+", "+geoplugin_countryName()); 
// window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";  /* you can forward user to url using this line of code according to your conditions
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link.

[How can I detect visitor's country and redirect he/she to an specific website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292128/how-can-i-detect-visitors-country-and-redirect-he-she-to-an-specific-website)

May be it will help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PECL's [`geoip_country_by_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php) with the user's ip address to get their country:

```
<?php


    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $country = geoip_country_name_by_name($ip);
    if ($country) {
        echo 'This host is located in: ' . $country;
        //header("Location: " . $somelocation);
    }
    ?>
```