# Automatically Detecting Which Country a User is in

Tags: java, html, css

Does anyone know how to automatically detect which country a user is in when browsing a website?

It is not so that the language changes, but the actual content changes and loads depending on which country the user is in - most specifically the contact details need to load differently from US to UK.

I have noticed that moo.com have somehow done it but have no clues.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185343/how-to-get-users-country-and-forward-to-url)

Comment: Here is for PHP one tip... you can combine it with Javascrit: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-name-by-name.php

Comment: Either one @AnubianNoob, just as long as it allows me to load different content depending on which country they are in.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exact country but rarely you will get the city.

you need to call google service to fetch user location.

```
http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp
```

or you can get the user location by using his latitude and longitude, by calling google service.

Comment: Will that then allow me to load different content, depending on which country the user is in @nAvEeD kHaN

Comment: @DavePentland, what do you mean with 'load different content'?

Comment: So, depending on if they are in UK or US it will load a different home page with slightly different contact details as well as a few other pages that are different @GabrielMuñumel